# Excel Find+Replace lowercase after a certain character

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, find-and-replace, wildcards

I have a column that requires specific formatting for summaries of articles. Everything after a *:* should appear as an uppercase for consitency

Example 1 - Markets: Comment on Ugandan Shilling

Example 2 - Stakes: Sale of business

There's a lot of this data and sometimes the summary is inputted with incorrect casing eg Markets: comment etc

How do I find and replace all lowercase letters after a : symbol with uppercase?

Answer (score 2):

Asuming only the first letter after ":" needs to be uppercase

```
=IF(FIND(":",A1)>0,REPLACE(A1,FIND(":",A1)+2,1,UPPER(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+2,1))),A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This formula should accomplish what you are looking for. It uses `ISNUMBER` to detect if there is a colon in the text. If it finds one, it concatenates everything before the colon with the upper case form of everything after the colon.

This formula assumes your text is located in cell `A1`.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(":",A1)), LEFT(A1, FIND(":", A1)-1)&UPPER(MID(A1, FIND(":", A1), LEN(A1))), A1)
```

[image: screenshot]